# How to get picklist input field value in Controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, picklist

I have an object with a picklist including two values "status" (Valid,Invalid).. I'm using search in my VF page dependent on the selected status from this picklist, so the SOQL should return the values where the status is equal "selected value".

While I'm searching for a solution I found this [example](http://www.salesforcefast.com/2011/06/get-picklist-values.html), put should I use this complex way ! I tried to get the value as following but i got error.

VF Page Code:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Account Search">
      <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:inputField id="status" value="{!account.Status__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockButtons>
           <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!getAccounts}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

AccController Code:

```
public Account Account{set;get;}
public list<Account> Accounts{set;get;}

public AccController(){
        Account= new Account();
    }

public PageReference getAccounts(){

        Accounts = Database.query('SELECT Name
                                   from Account
                                   WHERE Status__c = account.Status__c');
        return null;
    }
```

The Error : `System.QueryException: Variable does not exist: account.Status__c`
And If I put account.Status__c outside the singe comma like this `WHERE Status__c = ' + account.Status__c`
And Choose a value, for Example Valid, I got this Error

```
System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'Valid'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic `SOQL` bind variables can only be simple variables e.g. `:status` not dotted expressions such as references to fields e.g. `:account.Status__c` in the query string. [Here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) is the documentation.

In the same link you can find the solution; you assign your `account.Status__c` to a simple variable and use it in the query string instead:

```
String status = account.Status__c;
Accounts = Database.query('SELECT Name from Account WHERE Status__c = :status');
```

Comment: Someone reading just your first sentence would me misled: you "can’t use bind variable fields" but you "can use simple bind variables".

Comment: agreed @KeithC. I answered it by explaining as it required to the raised question and giving the details to what I'm saying. If it looks like misleading kindly update or let me know a better way to express it.

Comment: works fine with variable string `query = account.status__c;` `'... WHERE Status__c =: query';` thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help you. And it's pleasure to be a member of such a community where people support for the success of the community, @KeithC.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Accounts = Database.query('SELECT Name
                           From Account
                           WHERE Status__c =: account.Status__c');
```

Comment: no problem with this way, it works fine.. but I need to use Database.Query because I have more than Search Criteria, I'm using if statements to append search criteria

Comment: `System.QueryException: Variable does not exist: holiday.Status__c` but i put it in a variable with type string and it works fine !